# Is there a way to get infinite type arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a set of methods that accept type arguments:

```
public void Process<T>() { ... }
public void Process<T1, T2>() { ... }
public void Process<T1, T2, T3>() { ... }
```

Inside of these methods, I'm creating workers that execute sequentially, in the order specified by the type arguments, so for example:

```
public void Process<T1, T2>() {
    List<WorkerProcess> workers = GetWorkersFromTypes(typeof(T1), typeof(T2));
    if (workers?.Count > 0)
        foreach (var worker in workers)
            if (worker != null)
                worker.Process();
}
public List<WorkerProcess> GetWorkersFromTypes(params Type[] workerTypes) {
    var workers = new List<WorkerProcess>();
    foreach (var type in types) {
        if (type == typeof(WorkerA))
            workers.Add(new WorkerA());
        else if (type == typeof(WorkerB))
            workers.Add(new WorkerB());
    }

    return workers;
}
```

While this is effective, it's rather verbose using the `typeof` keyword. I'm wondering if there's something similar for type arguments that would enable something like this instead:

```
public void Process<T1, T2>() {
    List<WorkerProcess> workers = GetWorkersFromTypes<T1, T2>();
    ...
}
public List<WorkerProcess> GetWorkersFromTypes<params T[] types>() { ... }
```

In all my research, I'm coming to the conclusion that it is not possible, but there are much smarter and more effective researchers here that might be able to prove otherwise.

---

Is there a way to get infinite type arguments, in a manner similar to the `params` keyword, in C#?

Comment: I don't think so... https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,81

Comment: Unfortunate this was closed since I was going to post this as an answer, you might be able to implement your requirement by getting the constructors of the passed types with Reflection - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getconstructor?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetConstructor_System_Type___